# VSCode with cpptools: Usage of compile_commands.json results in wrong autocompletion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have set up visual studio code with the [cpptools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension and added this to my `c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
```

The content of `compile_commands.json` looks something like this (stripped it a bit)

```
[
  {
    "directory": "C:/projects/the_project/build",
    "command": "C:\\PROGRA~1\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe  /nologo -TP -DNOMINMAX -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Isrc\\Project -I..\\src\\Project /std:c++17 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1  /Fosrc\\Project\\CMakeFiles\\Project.dir\\main.cpp.obj /FdTARGET_COMPILE_PDB -c C:\\projects\\the_project\\src\\Project\\main.cpp",
    "file": "C:/projects/the_project/src/Project/main.cpp"
  }
]
```

So the project structure is

- root

  - build (cmake build directory)
  - src

    - Project

      - main.cpp
      - foo.h

So the relevant include path from is `-I..\\src\\Project`. The autocompletion I expect is `#include "foo.h"`but what I get is `#include "src/Project/foo.h"`

Anyone knows why the the path is not correctly resolved?

Comment: Did you set your `includePath`? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/release/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md

Comment: @JamesPoag Have no access to the project right now - But no I think the includePath was empty. VS Code should figure it out with the compile_commands.json file right? I mean that's the point?!

Comment: It was pretty good about picking up paths, but there were so many edge cases that weren't fixed until I added the paths manually.